# Change content with HTML radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code on my website.

```
<input type="radio" name="pricelist" onclick="online();" /> Show price with VAT
<br />
<input type="radio" name="pricelist" onclick="offline();" /> Show price without VAT
<br />
<span id="update"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function online(){
        document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "100$";
    }
    function offline(){
        document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "75$";
    }
</script>
```

I would like the "Show price with VAT" to be there when the user opens the page. It doesn't work with just "checked" for the form, unfortunately.

Do anyone of you have any idea how to solve this? :)

Answer (score 0):

On document.ready, check the radio via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onload event for this,

```
    <body onload="initial()">
       <input id="vat" type="radio" name="pricelist" onclick="online();" /> Show price with VAT
       <br />
       <input id="novat" type="radio" name="pricelist" onclick="offline();" /> Show price without VAT
       <br />
    </body>

function initial(){

   //automatically check the radio button
   document.getElementById("vat").checked = true;

   //call the function you want to call when page loads
   online();
}
```

[Here is a fiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/9jhn44k0/3/)

Don't forget to add an `id` to your radio buttons as vat and novat respectively.

If you want to use jQuery then you can use it's `ready()` function which will be executed when your page loads,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   initial();
});
```